# Export JavaFX Project to a runnable using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm using `Eclipse` and making a simple game in javaFX. I have images and need to package them and the javafx into a runnable file. I am not using any of the css stuff related to javafx, just the basic windows and stages and stuff. 
Thanks!

I have tried to just export it however it did not work.

Comment: You can use **javapackager** to package your JavaFX applications.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html

Comment: see file, export in the main menu. you can export a full jar

Comment: http://m.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse

Comment: It has to do also with the place where you have added the resources.Be carefull to add them into the Project folder..

Comment: Check this video, he creates the project from zero telling how to avoid common mistakes and creating executable and natvie installers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbjW8rYlook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- > Part 1
  >
  > **A JavaFX Eclipse Project is like:**

[image]

So with the above you are sure that every library and resource will be in the

1)Into the final Jar

**or**

2)You will have a final Jar and a separate folder which contains all the external libraries you are using.

**or**

3)  (2)+External Folder for other resources

> Exporting the Project:

1)Right Click on the Project

2)Export->Java->Runnable Jar File...

[image]

3)Choose your main class

4)On Library Handling it is your choice(better choose the **3rd** option cause it prevents conflicts on libraries which containing same classes and doesn't violate some libraries licence)

5)Export It

> Finally

Also have a look at this [link](http://m.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse) which was provided in the comments.

- > **Part 2)**

After you have done the above you can use [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to package your jar file into an .exe file(for Windows)

- > **Part 3)**

  You can also export your JavaFX Project in a way that it can be used in windows,Mac and Linux.

  For that you can use the file **build.fxbuild** and build the project(big topic search for it on internet)

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. How do i put the libraries into the resource folder because currently it only has the pictures in it.

Comment: @joe n drag and drop like you would be done it to a folder.

Comment: this answer is outdated; choosing the second option in Library handling (Package required libraries) gives: Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found; 
while the first library option (extract required libraries) gives the following error on running the jar: Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Comment: Please feel free to update, i am using IntelliJ as my main IDE now :)