# Eclipse: JavaFX Application Runs Fine In Eclipse but Does not run outside of it

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, export

Ok, so I created a new javaFX application that I am going to export for use on different devices. I have a PROPER launch config and it works fine in Eclipse.
BUT: When I run it outside of eclipse this happens.

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at com.Sample.Test.Window.Main.FileToDrive(Main.java:109)
    at com.Sample.Test.Window.Main.<init>(Main.java:36)
    at com.Sample.Test.Launcher.Launch.start(Launch.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 10 more
```

Now, I would say this has something to do with images. (`com.Sample.Test.Window.Main.FileToDrive(Main.java:109`) But I have Images above this line of code (line `47`) that seem to boot fine. Is this something to do with the automatic files that Eclipse places into the `jar` file?

Also 1 thing to note is that when the application runs. The Icon for java shows up briefly on the dock. Then disappears and the Terminal outputs the Exception.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am using Java 8. Does that mean that I still need to export the JavaFX library? If so, how would I go about doing that.

Edit: I tried exporting the library's into a seperate folder, but still seems to generate the same error

(Wow, another) Edit: I am using Mac OSX Yosemite.

Edit again: I built my project by going `File > Export > Java > Runnable Jar file > Entered The Launch Config > tried every method of exporting (Package, Export, LibAlongSide)`

Comment: do you export the javafx library? take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710286/export-javafx-project-to-a-runnable-using-eclipse

Comment: Check that upper and lower case match, when running in Eclipse you use the host file-system (on win32 it is case insensitive) if you run the exported version you are on the jar-file-system who is case sensitive

Comment: It's hard to say without any source code or image of your project structure. How did you build your jar file?