# Running java runnable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, executable-jar

I have created JavaFX app with OpenJDK13 and OpenJFX13. In Eclipse I have made Runnable JAR but it doesn't work (at least on my Win 10 installation) unless I add VM arguments in command line.

[image: Eclipse]

So, to fix this I made *.bat file with text:

```
java -jar --module-path  "C:\Java\javafx-sdk-13.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml Testing.jar
```

It working that way. But, there is 2 things about my solution I would like to change.

1. Is there any way to avoid Command prompt being shown when starting app?
2. Package required libraries into selected JAR is selected. When I remove

> --module-path  "C:\Java\javafx-sdk-13.0.1\lib"

from arguments in *.bat file it doesn't work. Any way to make it work without this? If I understand correctly end user should have everything he need in runnable JAR?

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710286/export-javafx-project-to-a-runnable-using-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating runnable jars is a very old-style technique. They would only work on the platform on which you have built them anyway due to the platform specific native code of JavaFX. So why not go the full way and create a real application for your platform? This can be done with the jpackage tool which comes with the EA release of JDK 14. Have a look here for a tutorial: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX .