# I made my javafx application in IntelliJ IDEA, so how I can use it without IDE or Windows Console?

Tags: java, javafx

I made my javafx application in IntelliJ IDEA, so how I can use/compile it without IDE or Windows Console? I just want to open it in my desktop. And send it to my friend to use.

Comment: You need to create executable .jar file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9463915/12609572

Comment: Oh please, don't tell people the wisdom from 10 years ago. Better have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800824/running-java-runnable-jar/59801777#59801777