# Eclispe: Export JavaFX14

Tags: eclipse, javafx, jar, export

I build an app in Eclipse using java14, javaFX14, FXML, XML and some audio files.
The app works great when I launch it in Eclipse, but when I export it as an jar file it's not working.

Source:
https://github.com/laPronoia/GameOfLife/tree/master/src

First I used simple export JAR, like in the link here:
[Export JavaFX Project to a runnable using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710286/export-javafx-project-to-a-runnable-using-eclipse)

The Error I get:

```
    JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Than I tried Package required libraries into generated JAR", which outputs the javaFX jar file into the Jar

The Errors I get:

```
va.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:42)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    Failed to load Glass factory class
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Finally I tried to setup a test using javaFX with Maven, but to make this work give me a whole new set of problems to deal with. I'm not even sure if Maven will help me with my problem.

This is my first app as a coder. Trying to export it introducest me to whole new realms of app development. I tryed to solve this for a week know and I'm not even sure  what to look for anymore.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. The classical approach of creating a runnable jar does not really work anymore for JavaFX with Java >= 11
2. The way to go is to create a self-contained applcation bundle via jpackage and some other tools. You can find a tutorial for non-modular projects here: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: Right you are mipa. I will look into this!

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way would be to provide JavaFX location and its dependencies in `cmd` like this:

`java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.swing -jar <path-to-your-jar-file>`

Comment: I have set my Path to the javaFX lib like this:
set PATH_TO_FX="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib"

and when I run my jar file: 
java -p "%PATH_TO_FX%" --add-modules javafx.controls -jar C:\Users\12213119\Desktop\GameOfLife.jar

I get the Error:
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib

Comment: Thx @smithnblack, some how I made it work. Not sure why %PATH_TO_FX% is not working out for me. I used   

--module-path $'/home/Documents/lib/javafx-sdk-14.0.1/lib' 

instead. Also I removed all the lines from the VM Argument in Eclipse. This way It would not interfere  with the added modules from the command line.