# creating a runnable JAR file _ missing VM arguments _ only runs with the IDE

Tags: java, javafx, arguments, virtual-machine

I've made a JavaFX application using eclipse, but sadly it does only work while running with the IDE.

When exporting the project as a runnable jar file, eclipse notes:

[image]

I guess it has something to do with JAR file missing the VM arguments. I don't know how to add them though.

When running through the terminal I get this:

[image]

I would the very thankful if you could help me get it running.
I've heard something about putting the file into a package, I am a bloody beginner though, and need a little help here.

I don't think it matters much, but I am using MacOS.

I need it as an executable file, so I just have to double click on the file and it runs. I need it for both MacOS and Windows.

If any further details are needed I will provide them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the command you used to run the jar file? I believe all you'd have to do is copy eclipse's vm arguments and paste them after your command

Comment: java -jar WidgetShortie.jar

I guess that's what you mean. 

The VM Arguments are in the IDE but for some reason, they don't translate to the runnable jar file.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. So basically you are trying to run your java application, which requires javafx. Usually eclipse tells your application where to find it(in the VM arguments). All you have to do is tell java where that library is located(since this differs per machine, eclipse can't do this for you). Simply try adding `--module-path="Add\path\to\JavaFX\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` to the command you are trying to run and change the --module-path to the path your javafx lib folder is located.

Comment: Your JVM is too new to include JavaFX.  You need to bring it yourself.

Comment: For some reason it tells me this despite being the very same path as in the IDE: `zsh: no such file or directory:--module-path=/Users/*****/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib`.  I need it as an executable file, so I just have to double click on the file and it runs. I need it for both MacOS and Windows.

Comment: Try having a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710286/export-javafx-project-to-a-runnable-using-eclipse)

Comment: You can't do this with just a jar file with modern JVMs (unless you're willing to expect users to do s significant amount of configuration). Create a native package instead; the `jpackage` tool is the easiest (imo) way to do this. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA as IDE .

It is not possible to add VM Arguments to jar file from IDE .

To do that manually follow these steps:

- Create .jar file from IDE.
- Create .bat file on windows and add VM Arguments like

  java --module-path MyPath\javafx-sdk-18.0.2\lib --add-modules   javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar MyApp.jar
- Change MyPath\javafx-sdk-18.0.2\lib by your javaFx sdk path and also change MyApp.jar to your jar name file
- Save, and execute the .bat file .